# Information management policy timer job is showing "N/A" for the Last Run Time

Tags: administration, timer-jobs, timer-service, monitoring

I want to run a timer job named "Information Management Policy", so I went to "Central Administration" >> "Job Definition". Then I ran the timer job manually, but it showed "N/A" beside the last run time, as follow:-

[image: screenshot]

Now I did these steps without being able to fix the problem :-

- Restart the Timer service (Start->Administrative Tools->Services) and IIS.
- I run the products configuration wizards.

Now I run this command :-

```
Start-SPTimerJob -Id dfd14b52-866a-4726-8149-5359638ffb35
```

Comment: does it appear under failed jobs?

Comment: Please provide timer-related logs (SPTimerV4), not w3wp

Comment: @Gwny no they do not even appear on job history. and can you please check my edit to the original question,, as i have provided some logs which might be related to my problem ? can you please check ?

Comment: @AzizKabyshev thanks for the reply,, please check my edit where i provided all logs entries which contain the word SPTimerV4 .. can you check and advice accordingly please ?

Comment: Let's launch the job manually and monitor ULS logs. Those you posted are related to other services, not what we're investigating.The page you screenshotted originally usually has this part in URL: `/_admin/JobEdit.aspx?JobId=bd814d1e%2De46a%2D4bff%2D90c6%2Da389e83691c2&Source=`. Get that GUID between '=' and '&', replacing "%2D" with "-" if present. Then open SP 2013 Management Shell, and execute `Start-SPTimerJob -Id _GUID_`. Now check logs for lines containing `Entering monitored scope (Timer Job` from 'OWSTIMER.EXE'

Comment: @AzizKabyshev ok i run the following command "Start-SPTimerJob -Id dfd14b52-866a-4726-8149-5359638ffb35" and i provided the logs, can you check my original question please?

Comment: Oops, your question lost the screenshot. Would you please create a chat?

Comment: @AzizKabyshev the screen shot is not necessary , but i have provided the realted logs after running this command Start-SPTimerJob -Id dfd14b52-866a-4726-8149-5359638ffb35

Comment: Those entries are not related. Can you create a chat? I don't have points count required. Follow [this steps](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) and invite me there.

Comment: @AzizKabyshev can you please join http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35866/information-management-policy-timer-job-is-showing-n-a-for-the-last-run-time